# Is this sentence correct or not? Why hadn't you have lunch with her?

Tags: grammar, british-english

If wrong, then whether there is any rule?

Comment: Use either *why*  ***didn't*** *you* ***have*** *lunch* or *why* ***haven't*** *you* ***had*** *lunch*.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly *have*, when used as a modal verb, takes a past participle not an infinitive so

*Why hadn't you **had** lunch with her?*

Secondly did you want to use the pluperfect? This is for something before something else in the past:

*Why hadn't you had lunch with her before you proposed to her?*

You could use the present perfect if you mean "before now"

*Why haven't you had lunch with her [yet]?*

But the simple past would be the most universally appropriate:

*Why didn't you have lunch with her?*